# Como faço para criar uma view no mysql pegando dados de 2 ou mais tabelas diferentes?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

[image]
To Começando a ver View em banco de dados agora, mais surgiu uma duvida neste exercício, tenho que visualizar itens de 3 tabelas diferentes mais não sei como.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você deveria ter colocado o qua já fez.

Como você é novato vou responder abaixo mas faça um [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) sobre como usar este site.

```
CREATE VIEW ProdutosPendentes AS 
SELECT LstCompras.NmLstCompras, GrpProduto.NmGrpProduto, Produto.NmProduto 
  FROM Produto  INNER JOIN GrpProduto ON (Produto.CdGrpProduto = GrpProduto.CdGrpProduto)
                    INNER JOIN Anota ON (Produto.CdProduto = Anota.CdProduto)
                    INNER JOIN LstCompras ON (Anota.CdLstCompras = LstCompras.CdLstCompras)
  WHERE Anota.InCompra = ' '
  ORDER BY LstCompras.NmLstCompras ASC, GrpProduto.NmGrpProduto ASC, Produto.NmProduto ASC;
```